# How to diff files/folders in Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle, diff, build-process

I need to write a script in Gradle that takes as an input 2 folders. 
Both folders contain <1000 files (mostly images) with reasonably similar structure.
The output should be a list of files that changed and what kind of difference it is (added file/deleted file/changed file).

Edit: Heres a sample script https://gist.github.com/igormukhin/71d780c4274336eeb297 . The only problem is that it compares by timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently coded up something similar to what you are asking for: [DirectoryDifferenceCollector](https://github.com/cjstehno/vanilla/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/stehno/vanilla/io/DirectoryDifferenceCollector.groovy); however, it actually compares the contents of the files (as a hash) and not the timestamp. I would be willing to update it to accept a configurable strategy if that would suit your needs, or you can just use the concepts involved.

Basically it scans both directories and determines the missing files in both A and B and then it also determines which files are common to both directories, but have different content.

The results are collected in a DirectoryDifference object with the respective file paths for each category.

Comment: Excellent, this looks like what I need :) I need to compare binary contents, not just timestamps. This will be part of our art build pipelile for a script that generates .zip files which contain the changed/updated art assets. I will need to make some other small changes (The script will abort if the first parameter directory contains a file that the second parameter does not)

Comment: The code referenced in this answer seems to have moved due to a refactoring to a single level project. It appears to be at [here](https://github.com/cjstehno/vanilla/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/stehno/vanilla/io/DirectoryDifferenceCollector.groovy)
now.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be tempted to use [`diff`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/diff/):

```
def process = 'diff x y'.execute()
```

You can then access the output of the command as text:

```
println process.err.text
println process.in.text
```

And get the exit status via:

```
int status = process.waitFor()
```

Many common operating systems will come with `diff` installed, but Windows probably does not.

Comment: It needs to be platform agnostic, thats why I use Gradle.

Comment: That's odd, the version I'm looking at right now still isn't.